# how to generate salt in yii?

Tags: yii, salt

I'm working on `user management` in my project and I got to the part where I need to store the `passwords` in the `database`. I read that the `password` should be `crypt` with the `salt` and be kept together. However I didn't seem to find out how do I generate a `random salt` for each new `user`. 
Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously suggest you use [CPasswordHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper/).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22);
$salt = '$2a$%13$' . strtr($salt, array('_' => '.', '~' => '/'));
$password_hash = crypt($form->password, $salt);
```

And

```
if ($password_hash === crypt($form->password, $password_hash))
    // password is correct
else
    // password is wrong
```

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/425/use-crypt-for-password-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly relevant to your answer, but I use this excellent extension [Yii extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpass/) which takes all the guesswork out of creating and storing passwords in Yii

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is pretty good. I'd actually recommend using YiiPassword (https://github.com/phpnode/YiiPassword) as it gives you a lot of flexibility.

But yes, when it comes to passwords and security, *far* better not to reinvent the wheel. The likelihood is that you'll end up with security issues unless you are really careful.

Answer (score 0):

try `$this -> salt = uniqid('',true);` and use `$this->password = $this->hashPassword($this->password, $this->salt);}` for salt encrypting user`s password

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Yii, but actually you should be able to use PHP's native function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate the hash, and the function [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check whether the password matches the hash. This function will handle all the tricky parts like generating a safe salt, and will include the salt in the resulting hash.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```